# Django calling function in URL for views

Tags: python, django

I am confused with these two different syntaxes of using views in the URL. For generic views we use this

```
views.myview.as_view()
```

But if i need to use my own custom function for view then i need to use

```
views.myview().myfunction
```

Why is there difference between the two

why not `views.myview.myfunction` is working

Answer (score 2):

Views can be written as either classes or functions. If you're not worried about re-using code, then functions are probably easier. Have a look at the [docs for writing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/). Then maybe have a quick look at the [docs for class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/). Lastly check the docs for the [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/).

View functions are written like this -

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return HttpResponse()
```

A view function is called by passing the function into urlpatterns as follows -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from views import my_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^my_page/$', my_view)
)
```

Class based views allow you to reuse functionality through inheritance.

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class MySpecialDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
    # add functionality here
```

The problem is that the url setup is expecting a function, not a class. That's where the `as_view()` function comes in. Class based views are called in the url conf as -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from views import MySpecialDetailView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^my_special_page/$', MySpecialDetailView.as_view())
)
```

Apologies if I've mis-understood your question

Comment: The only thing i more need to know is that if suppose instead of as_view() function u need to call `as_view_custom()` function then the synatx chnages to `MySpecialDetailView().as_view_custom`. i just want to know why

Comment: Don't call as_view_custom(). Override as_view() in a new class based view and call that instead. Why would you need to call as_view_custom()?

Comment: I know i can do that. but i just want to know why is the diff

Answer (score 0):

The `as_view()` class method creates a view function that will create a new instance of the `View` class and then pass control to its `dispatch` method.  So you will have a different instance of the view used to service each request.

In your second example, you are only creating one instance of the view, and using a bound method as the view function.  This means that the same instance is used to service every request (which also means it could be used concurrently by two requests.  This shared state won't be obvious to people who don't read your urlconf, so could result in bugs.

If you just need to dispatch to a different method, consider overriding `dispatch`.  You can pass keyword arguments to `as_view` that will be available as instance attributes in `dispatch` if you need different behaviour from the view in different places.

If you need to share some state between different requests, consider using something more explicit than attributes on a shared instance of the view class.

Comment: I have two questions. 1. `Under what condition/ use case we need to sahre some state in diff request` and `how we can do it right way`. 2. `how can i overiride the dispatch function. any example tut`

Comment: (1) you may want to cache things between requests, or even try to store things permanently.  Django has better options for both of those. (2) what do you want the method to do exactly?  You didn't explain why you needed to name your method `myfunction` rather than `dispatch`, `get` or whatever.